# This double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$  \int_0^1\int_0^1x^3y^2\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\hspace{1mm}dxdy$$

We have to compute this up to 4 decimal places

Comment: And what have you attempted so far?

Comment: I tried by substituting $u = 1+x^2+y^2$, I am stuck

Comment: This is a double integral, so a single substitution like that doesn't work. Do you know about change of variables and Jacobians?

Comment: Two words: Polar Coordinate.

Comment: @satishramanathan It must be the same. If not, then the problem is in the integral limit.

Comment: @user155188 If you know nothing about change of variables and Jacobian, try substitution $x=\sqrt{1+y^2}\tan t$.

Comment: The region you are integrating over is a square, yours is a circle.

Comment: @Could you then let know how you could transform it in polar?

Comment: @satishramanathan : $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec\theta} f(r,\theta)\, dr\, d\theta+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\csc\theta} f(r,\theta)\, dr\, d\theta \approx 0.125065481458092$$

Comment: @gar,I just figured out.  Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Okay, no problem.

Comment: But still, its quite a challenge to solve it in polar coordinates too.

Comment: You bet!! It was a challenge for me to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need an approximation of this integral, you could use numerical methods. Matlab or [Wolfram's Double Integral Calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a), for example, can do it just fine :

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{3}y^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}+y^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \simeq 0.125065 $$

But if you want an exact computation, this might be harder.

To begin with, I wouldn't use polar coordinates here because you integrate on the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and the parametrization of this unit square in polar coordinates is not straightforward.

Let

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{3}y^{2} \sqrt{1+x^{2}+y^{2}} \, \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d}y.$$

Using Fubini's theorem, you can write :

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} y^{2} \Bigg( \int_{0}^{1} x^{3} \sqrt{1+y^{2}+x^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \Bigg) \, \mathrm{d}y. \tag{1}$$

Now, we have to compute an integral of this form :

$$ J=\int_{0}^{1} x^{3} \sqrt{a+x^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

with $a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. This can be done using two changes of variable :

$$
\begin{align*}
J &= {} \int_{0}^{1} x^{3} \sqrt{a+x^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\[2mm]
 & \mathop{=} \limits_{u=x^2} \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} u \sqrt{a+u} \, \mathrm{d}u \\[2mm]
 & = \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{a+1} (v-a)\sqrt{v} \, \mathrm{d}v \\[2mm]
 & = \frac{1}{5} (a+1)^{\frac{5}{2}} + \frac{2}{15}a^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{a}{3}(a+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

As a consequence, $(1)$ becomes :

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1} y^{2} \Big[ \frac{1}{5}(2+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}} + \frac{2}{15}(1+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{1}{3}(1+y^{2})(2+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}} \Big] \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

At this point, we have to compute the three following integrals :

$$I_{1} = \int y^{2}(1+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}y, \quad I_{2} = \int y^{2}(1+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \quad \mathrm{and} \quad I_{3} =\int (1+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}y.$$

One method to compute these integrals (it might not be the easiest way) would be to consider the change of variable $y = \sinh(t)$. Even though, the computation is not completely straightforward. If you want, I can give more explanations about the computation of these integrals. [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) gives the following results :

$$
\begin{align*}
I_{1} & = {} \frac{1}{8} \Big( 19\sqrt{3} - 5 \sinh^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big) \Big) \\
I_{2} & = \frac{1}{384} \big( 317\sqrt{2} - 15 \sinh^{-1}(1) \big) \\
I_{3} & = \frac{1}{8} \Big( 11\sqrt{3} - \sinh^{-1}\big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big) \Big)
\end{align*}
$$

In the end :

> $$I = \frac{317\sqrt{2} - 15 \sinh^{-1}(1)}{2880} + \frac{1}{40}\Bigg(19\sqrt{3}-5\sinh^{-1} \Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big) \Bigg)+\frac{1}{24}\Bigg( \sinh^{-1}\Bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big) - 11\sqrt{3} \Bigg).$$

Comment: interesting, thank you for your effort :)